# как получить только категории третьего уровня?

Tags: wordpress

У меня множество категорий такого вида:

Категория 1 > Субкатегория 1 > Субсубкатегория 1

Категория 2 > Субкатегория 1 > Субсубкатегория 1

Как мне получить массив с ID только субсубкатегорий? Пробовал указывать parent=0, но тогда какраз таки мне только Родительские главные категории и выводит.

```
$categories =  get_terms(
                'category', 
                array('order'=> 'DESC', 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty'  => 1) 
                );
foreach($categories as $category) {
 echo $category->term_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$all_categories = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => 1,

));

$third_level = array_filter($all_categories, function ($t) {
  return $t->parent != 0 && get_term($t->parent, 'category')->parent != 0;
});

$third_level_ids = array_map(function ($t) {
  return $t->term_id;
}, $third_level);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, то что нужно!